# add div main-content in magento 2x

Tags: magento2, page-layouts

How to add div main-content above in magento 2.2

[image]

please advance thanks for help

Comment: Please check my answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
    <container name="custom.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-view" after="breadcrumbs">
        <block class="namespace\module\Block\entity" name="customView" template="namespace_module::custom.phtml" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Flush cache and clear cache and check it.

Comment: <main id="maincontent" class="page-main"></main> above

Comment: Please add HTML example to understand proper.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this, below code is working for me.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="page.wrapper.second" as="page_wrapper_second" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-wrapper-second" before="main.content">
               <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="custom_menu_link">
                     <arguments>
                          <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">custom_menu_link</argument>
                     </arguments>
               </block>
        </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

you have to place your block instead of "**custom_menu_link**" block. The container should a child block or container.

Answer (score 0):

Add your layout below code :

```
<container name="custom.div" as="custom-div" label="div Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom_div">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  template="Magento_Theme::customview.phtml">
</container>
```

Make a phtml file call **customview.phtml** in Magento_Theme under template folder and put some html content.

Move the container as from your layout below above code:

```
<move element="custom.div" destination="page.wrapper" before="main.content"/>
```

Comment: not working check it

Comment: I have modified my answer. please check